# Angular2 ngModel: Why can it change an immutable string?

Tags: javascript, string, angular, immutability, angular-ngmodel

I am kind of confused here.
Using ngModel i can do the following:

```
import {NgModel} from "angular2/common";
@Component({
  selector: "test",
  template: `<input tpye="text" [(ngModel)]="strInObj.str">  {{strInObj|json}}`,
  directives: [NgModel]
})
class Test{
  strInObj: {str: string} = {str: "this is a string"};
}
```

Now when i type in the input, the `strInObj.str` gets updated. I am confused by this, because as far as i know strings are immutable, and there is no way of finding the parent of a reference.

In this case I pass the `str` property directly, meaning that `ngModel` gets a reference to the string. If it "changes" the string on that reference a new one is created therefore not changing the original string, which `strInObj.str` points to. At least that is my understanding.
And there is no way of finding the parent of the reference passed to ngModel (there is no concept like `str.parent()`, which would return `strInObj`)
So how do they do this? I tried to understand the ts and js sources, but...well, here i am.

I tried to build a similar directive, but ended up only beeing able to pass objects that wrap strings, i have not found a way to modify the original object when passing the `str` property directly....  (in the example i would pass `strInObj` to my directive, which then would work with the `str` property of the passed object, which works fine).

I'd be glad if someone could help me unriddle this :)

**EDIT**
[In this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rJXQUYKsd2aAN5TgsIQn?p=preview) i have my custom directive `StrDirective` and an input field with a NgModel directive. Both have the same binding `exampleStr` which is outputted in a simple span.
Now, when i enter text in the input, you can see `exampleStr` being updated. This is expected behaviour. I know that this works.
The `StrDirective` updates its binding when clicked on. You can see that it updates its "working copy" of the string, but `exampleStr` is not getting updated.
My Question is now: How do they do it / How can i get my directive to update `ExampleStr` without having to wrap it in an Object?

Comment: angular keep this `"strInObj.str"` to know which property update on the model. then `this.strInObj.str = "newvalue"` do the job. Same as you are doing.

Comment: You don't have to pass `strInObj.str`, just pass `str`. This works because you're passing a model to `ngModel` with two-way binding.

Comment: @hackedto where does angular2 store it, and how can i myself access this information when passing values to an input of a directive?

Comment: @pixelbits i know that it works with ngModel, the question was why/how.

Comment: @ch40s I don't know angular, sorry. You could use the debugger to check if  it's stored somewhere. It could also be compiled into a custom getter/setter added on the model.

Comment: Angular2 resolves bindings to component properties, so when you bind to `str`, you're binding to a `str` string property on the component. The change detection strategy does reference checks to determine if a binding has changed.

Comment: @pixelbits yes i know :) It seems we are misunderstanding each other. Anyways i found a solution. EDIT: no i didnt. Please try to write a directive that gets a string as input and modifies the string that was passed to the directive, instead of only modifiying its "working copy" of the string

Comment: @ch40s I understand now:) your plnkr made it clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Javascript, all strings are immutable. When someone types in an input field, it updates the "working copy" of the string so that the working copy points to a new reference.  Or put another way, every time the string changes, its a new string reference.

When a key is pressed that changes the model, `ngModelChange` output event is triggered, which then updates parent component's model with the new reference. The references are now in sync. When you say "modify the string that was passed to it", that's not possible because strings are immutable.

When there is two-way binding to a model:

```
[(ngModel)]="str"
```

The binding is equivalent to:

```
[ngModel]="str" (ngModelChange)="str=$event"
```

The `@Output` `ngModelChange` event is triggered whenever `str` (which the model is bound to) changes. In this way, a change in reference is propagated upwards to all components where two-way model binding is setup, so that each model points to the same reference.

**[Edit]**

In the Plnkr from the updated question, it shows that two-way binding is being restored after the user types a key in the input box. The question is how and why?

To understand what's happening let's look at the two scenarios:

1. User clicks the label and the event handler is triggered which changes the bound @Input value
2. User types a key in the input box.  Both labels are automatically re-bound to the same reference, and two-way model binding works for both labels.

Before the user clicks the label, all bindings are in sync:

```
                       S1 (app component)
                       /\
(exampleStr binding) S1  S1 (str component)
```

After the click event, the bound @Input model changes. Then, a round of change detection occurs starting from the root and working its way to the child components in depth first order.  Since the @Input binding propagates downwards, nothing really changes to the other bindings.

In the first scenario, this is the state of the bindings after the click event:

```
                       S1 (app component)
                       /\
(exampleStr binding) S1  S2 (str component)
```

When the user starts to type in the textbox which has two-way binding setup, it triggers an `ngModelChange` event which changes the value of `exampleStr` to `S3`.

```
                       S3 (app component)
                       /\
(exampleStr binding) S3  S2 (str component)
```

The default change detection strategy then kicks in, which starts from the root and works its way down to the child components in depth first order.

The state of the bindings after a key is pressed is:

```
                       S3 (app component)
                       /\
(exampleStr binding) S3  S3 (str component)
```

As you can see, all the bindings are in sync again. The default change detection strategy checks all components; changes to the model are propagated through the component's `@Input` bindings in a predictable and uni-directional flow from parent to child.

To understand how change detection works, think of it happening in phases. This is over-simplified, but it may help with your understanding:

1. Input bindings are propagated from root to children. Angular keeps track of which models are bound to which input properties. This is needed later for change detection.
2. An event fires (such as a click event) which modifies @Input properties. With two-way model binding, the change in model is propagated upwards from child to parent.
3. After the event fires, a single round of change detection is triggered starting from the root (repeat step 1) to re-sync all the bindings. During this process, all application and view bindings are updated.

Note: Angular uses zones to monkey-patch browser events, so it knows to when to trigger change detection.

**[Edit]**

If you want the message to be updated when the label is clicked, setup two-way binding like you would with ngModel:

```
@Input("str") value : string;
@Output("strChange") valueChange:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();


onClick(){
  this.value = "new string";
  this.valueChange.next(this.value);
}
```

HTML

```
<span [(str)]="exampleStr"></span><br>
```

[Demo Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RmSJ1R7jVEXreP5pTvmx?p=preview)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to type this out, but it seems i failed to explain what i want to understand. i will edit my question with a plunkr in a sec.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, a plunkr would help:)

Comment: But how do they achieve to update the root S1 to S3, when javaScript offers no mechanism to find a parent object? NgModel can do it, but how do they setup this two way data binding? I want to be able to the same thing in my directive: changing the root (in your example).

Comment: Through the two-way model binding that was setup with ngModel. The two-way binding changes the model, which is then propagated downwards starting from the root..

Comment: This is where we talk past each other ^^ I want to know how the two way data binding works, at least with strings. On Objects i understand it, but since strings are immutable i dont understand how they do it

Comment: hopefully its clear how its done based on my explanation

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for your efforts. But i know everything you just explained, again. The problem is i want to know how they internally do it, so i can use it on my own directive (or somehow wrap the ngModel directive). I ask how two-way bindings work, but i mean internally - how angular2 achieves that with the js restrictions i mentioned in OP. You gave me the conceptual answer for that. I have looked at ngModels typescript source, but it didn't help me all that much. I'm guessing they are doing it with the reflection api or something, but my knowledge about their internals is "meh" atm...

Comment: Ah i see, I hope you get the answer you're looking for

Comment: just saw this again.....i don't know why i was so stuck that day, even after you told me exactly what makes it possible. ngModel doesn't magically find the root of anything, it's simply the output that has a direct reference to the string: (ngModel)="str = $event". I use that mechansim all the time, i don't know how i twisted that. Nevertheless, thanks again for the patience you had with me:) i have accepted your answer